# How can I stop my Header links to wrap when testing for window size?

Tags: css, material-ui

[image]

The image above is how my header normally looks, the image below is what happens when I start to shrink the window size.

[image]

What CSS can I use to stop the Text navLinks to stop wrapping like that?

Here is the CSS I use:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    // appBar is the CSS for the material-UI component
    appBar: {
        borderBottom: `1px solid ${ theme.palette.divider }`,
        flexGrow: 1,
        "@media (max-width: 1000px)": {
            paddingLeft: 0,
        }
    },
    // toolBar is the CSS wrapper for all <divs> inside the appBar
    toolBar: {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center",
        padding: "0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 1rem",
    },
    // LOGO text
    toolbarTitle: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        fontFamily: 'Track',
        textAlign: "left",
        margin: "0.5rem",
        paddingLeft: "100px",
        "@media (max-width: 1000px)": {
            marginLeft: "20px",
            paddingLeft: 0,
        }
    },
    // Here are my navLinks that are wrapping and causing the problem.
    navLinks: {
        fontWeight: 700,
        size: "18px",
        marginLeft: "70px",
        padding: "0 1rem",
        float: "center",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        overflow: "hidden",
        display: "inline-block",
    },
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example

```
@media (max-width: 700px)": {
            navlinks{margin-left: 30px,}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries, size is % and inline blocks.

Comment: In the image down you have a lots of space arround links, you use media queries for size of device and add less space arround links, maybe you can give smaller font size, ehat you want ...